# add_action not being called inside another function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call add_action from another function in this way:

Using this:

```
$this->add_action('most-rated', 'get_most_rated');
```

Instead of this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
   register_rest_route('app-api', 'most-rated', [
        'methods' => 'GET', 
        'callback' => [$this, 'get_most_rated'],
    ]);
}, 10);
```

Where add_action is:

```
public function add_action($route, $endpoint, $request = 'GET') {
    add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route('app-api', $route, [
            'methods' => $request, 
            'callback' => [$this, $endpoint],
        ]);
    }, 10);
}
```

The code is working and not sending any errors as the code after it is still being called, but the EndPoint isn't being added.

Am I doing something wrong that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

`$route`, `$endpoint` and `$request` are not in the scope of the anonymous function, you can add a `use` statement for accessing them inside the function.

```
public function add_action($route, $endpoint, $request = 'GET') {
    add_action('rest_api_init', function () use ($route, $endpoint, $request) {
        register_rest_route('app-api', $route, [
            'methods' => $request, 
            'callback' => [$this, $endpoint],
        ]);
    }, 10);
}
```